# Accessing Citrix User Information from C#-Application

Tags: c#, active-directory, citrix

A customer wants to display user information in a winform upon logon (like the time until the password expires). These are Active Directory Users

As I am completely new to Citrix:

1. Can I just access active directory like here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C
   or does this only work on Windows-Users but not Citrix
2. Do I have to publish that application on every client or do I just deploy on a server?
3. What is the best way to save settings on that environment? Can I use the Registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes standard AD stuff works fine in a Citrix environment. To all intents and purposes you can consider Citrix usage of your server to be the same as normal "Windows" usage. While Citrix provides it's own custom management and brokering layer, once the user connects to a Windows session it is largely the same.

For deployment your app would need to be installed on every Citrix server. However how the app gets accessed depends on what your customer wants. Is it meant to be some self service app that the users explicitly choose to launch? Or is it something that runs and pops up when users launch other applications?

If it's an app the users explicitly launch, then the Citrix admin will need to publish that app using the Citrix admin console. If it's something that should launch for other apps then the customer would need to configure some form of login script to startup the app when users start sessions on Citrix servers.

For settings you generally want to store stuff in the user's roaming profile. This can either be files or the registry. For the registry you should use the current user hive (HKCU). As long as roaming profiles are setup properly, anything written to HKCU should follow the user across servers. For files lookup the appropriate environment variables to get the roaming profile path. You will end up writing stuff to a location like:

c:\users\\appdata\roaming\\file.whatever

Note the "roaming" path after "appdata" - that's the roaming part of the profile. Anything in appdata\local never leaves that particular machine.

For global settings you would use the local machine hive (HKLM). You can only write to this hive if you have local admin privileges on the machine. There are two main ways you generally setup such settings:

1. In the installer of your application. You would have a UI page in the installer where the admin could change the value of the setting. The setting would get written to a location like: HKLM\Software\CompanyName\ProductName\SomeKey. Generally the admin would then automate deployment of the MSI to his servers, with the appropriate value included in the MSI deployment script (rather than having to manually execute the MSI on all the servers).
2. Use the same key as above, but use Group Policy to configure the setting. While admins can make GPOs to edit any reg key, generally you would provide an ADM template to make it easier for admins to do this if using GPOs is the recommended method to change the setting for your app. See this link:
   http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2007/08/14/deploying-custom-registry-changes-through-group-policy.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Just one more question: The setting I want to store is not user-related, but a "global" setting set by the admiinstrator.  Where should those be saved.?

Comment: I've added extra detail to the bottom of the answer for global settings.